# Angular, browserify, directive controllers not available

Tags: angularjs, browserify

I'm testing out angular and browserify. Supposed to be drop dead simple and straight forward. Only it's not :( Here is my problem:

I have a dir structure in my src folder like so:

```
src/
 js/
  controller/
   index.js
   controller1.js
   ......
  directive/
    index.js
    directive1.js
    directive2.js
```

My directive/index.js looks like this:

```
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('seisTools');
app.directive('fillController', require('./fill_controller'));
app.directive('fill', require('./fill'));
```

My problem directive looks like this (fill.js):

```
'use strict';
module.exports = function(){
    return{
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {},
        require: '^fillController',
        link: function (scope, element, attr, ctrl) {
            var parent = $(element).parents('[fill]').get(0);
            var config = JSON.parse(attr.fill);
            ctrl.manageLayout(element, parent, config);
        }
    }
}
```

The fillController directive looks like this:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function($window, $timeout){
    return {
        controller: function($scope){
            var me = this;
            me.manageElement = function(child, parent, config){
                console.log('managing an element');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It requires the fillController but browserify isn't making it available. How do i get browserify to make this fillController available to my fill directive ? I put them in the right order, this is supposed to be a synchronous thing, why aren't they getting created in the right order like in a synchronous environment ?

Thanks !

Comment: Just to make sure I understand, you are using both directives in your HTML, right? With the `fill` directive as a child of the `fillController` directive?

Comment: Hi. the fillController directive does not appear in my html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use both directives in your HTML for [the `require` option](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-require-) to work as you're intending. I recommend something like this.

HTML:

```
<div fill fill-controller></div>
<!-- OR -->
<div fill-controller>
  <div fill></div>
</div>
```

fill.js:

```
// ...
// This will instruct the directive to look for the fillController directive
// on the same element the fill directive is on or a parent of it
require: '^fillController',
// ...
```